# Laravel/PHP Excel get rows till it returns empty array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Currently with my function i am getting al the rows of my excel sheet. Some of these rows contains data i don't want. After the usefull data i created a empty row.

If the loop reaches this row it should stop. How can i check if a row (array) has 0 values.

[image]

```
  $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();

    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) use (&$excel) {

           $objExcel = $reader->getExcel();
           $sheet = $objExcel->getSheet(0);
           $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
           $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

           //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
           for ($row = 10; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
           {

               //  Read a row of data into an array
               $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

               $excel[] = $rowData[0];

           }
      dd($excel);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition like this condition :

```
if(!empty($rowData[0])){
     [Your code to populate your excell array]
}
```